# SQLAlchemy "Table already exists" but "checkfirst=True" is defined

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

im working on a Flask app which uses SQLAlchemy for DB handling.

When testing locally with sqlite everything works as expected. The Production config is MySQL (MariaDB 11). When i deploy it to my server, i get errors that the table already exists.

I installed MariaDB locally and tested it, also no issues. It only happens on the servers MariaDB.

The Error is `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1050, "Table 'events' already exists")`

`init_db()` is called with app context.

Im wondering why it works locally with the same MariaDB 11 server config, and how it can happen when i explicitly define `checkfirst=True`. Afaik this should add `IF NOT EXISTS` to the db queries.

database.py

```py
from .config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy  # noqa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, scoped_session, sessionmaker


engine = create_engine(
    Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=3600
)

db_session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
)


class CustomBase:
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(self):
        return self.__name__.lower()


Base = declarative_base(
    metadata=MetaData(
        naming_convention={
            "ix": "ix_%(column_0_label)s",
            "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
            "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
            "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
            "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s",
        }
    ),
    cls=CustomBase,
)


def init_db():
    import apps.models  # noqa

    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)


def update(self, data):
    # Update an object with the data provided
    for key, value in data.items():
        if hasattr(self, key) and value is not None:
            setattr(self, key, value)


Base.query = db_session.query_property()
Base.update = update
```

models.py

```py
from .database import Base
from datetime import date
from flask_security import AsaList, RoleMixin, UserMixin
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, DateTime, Float, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableList
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref, relationship

class Events(Base):  # type: ignore
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    event_type = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    room_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("rooms.id"), nullable=True)
    plant_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("plants.id"), nullable=True)
    event_date = Column(String(100), default=str(date.today()), nullable=False)
    event_notes = Column(String(10000), default=None, nullable=True)
    event_image_path = Column(String(100), default=None, nullable=True)
    date_added = Column(String(100), default=str(date.today()))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Event %r>" % self.id

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "event_type": self.event_type,
            "room_id": self.room_id,
            "plant_id": self.plant_id,
            "event_date": self.event_date,
            "event_notes": self.event_notes,
            "event_image_path": self.event_image_path,
            "date_added": self.date_added,
        }
```

I expect that SQLAlchemy skips creation of tables when they are already present.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.